# How do I change the default sorting order for Thunderbird search results?

Tags: thunderbird

When I run a search in Thunderbird (currently running version 13.0.1), the results default to being sorted by relevance.  I generally find it much more useful to me, to have them sorted by date instead.

Is there a way I can change this default behavior?

Comment: It drives me crazy that it won't default to date.  I have never found "relevance" useful when I'm searching for a lost message.

Answer (score 3):

This extension will help you: [Search Results Sort By Date Not Relevance](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/search-results-sort-by-date-no/).