# Always open search queries as time-sorted list in Thunderbird 68?

Tags: thunderbird, search

Thunderbird 68 has a useful index based search feature across all emails, which is much more convenient than using the old search interface for most queries.

However, I find myself repeating the same workflow every time I use it:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, search term, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Click "Open email as list", because the verbose search interface really doesn't help me to find emails.

Is there any way to automate this and just directly show the results as a list?

### Similar questions

There is an older question [How do I change the default sorting order for Thunderbird search results?](https://superuser.com/questions/445308/how-do-i-change-the-default-sorting-order-for-thunderbird-search-results), but the suggested addon doesn't exist anymore and, with the answer being from 2012, likely wouldn't be compatible either way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was requested in Bug 580252
[Faceted Search: Option to make "Open as List" view the default view](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=580252).

This bug report was opened 10 years ago and was continuously being swamped
with more user requests, until the Thunderbird team menaced to block all comments.
Four months ago, as complaints did not stop, the team carried out this menace
and blocked the bug report, in effect refusing it.

The bug report's status is still left as "NEW", after 10 years, which shows
how seriously this is taken by the team...

One developer created as solution the add-on
[Search as list](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/search-as-list/),
but it was rendered unusable in the latest versions of Thunderbird.

In short, your chances for getting this feature are rather hopeless.

Comment: Every time I try to use Thunderbird (few days in), I find something stupid and outrageous like that. I should probably stop trying and accept that no simple email client exists anymore. Everything needs to be fancy with "predicted search" or whatever that useless search panel suppose to represent.

/rant

Answer (score 1):

My workaround using AHK v2:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

#HotIf (WinActive("ahk_class MozillaWindowClass")) ; Thunderbird Window Class
^k:: { ; CTRL+K hotkey

    SearchString := InputBox("Please enter your search term:", "Search Thunderbird", "", "").value
    if (SearchString == "")  ; If user presses Cancel or closes the InputBox, nothing happens
        return

    WinActivate("ahk_class MozillaWindowClass") ; Activates the Thunderbird window
    Sleep(500)
    Send("^k") ; Sends CTRL+K to Thunderbird to focus on the search bar
    Send(SearchString . "`n") ; Sends the search string followed by ENTER
    
    Sleep(1500)
    Send("{Esc}")
    
    ; Coordinates for the "Show Results as Text" button
    MouseClick("left", 967, 160)
    Sleep(500) ; Wait for the new tab with the search results to open

    Send("^+{Tab}") ; CTRL+SHIFT+TAB to go back to the faceted search tab
    Sleep(100) ; Waits a moment for the tab switch
    Send("^w") ; CTRL+W to close the faceted search tab
    
    Sleep(100)  ; Wait 100 milliseconds after closing the tab
    Send("!v")  ; ALT+V
    Sleep(100)  ; Wait a bit for the menu to open
    Send("s")  ; 's' key
    Sleep(100)  ; Wait a bit for the submenu
    Send("h")  ; 'h' key
    return
}

#HotIf
```

Comment: Thanks, still working with thunderbird 115 with adaptation for MouseClick coordinates (use Autohotkey desktop "Windows Spy" feature to find them) and slower sleep delays (except for the 1500ms one because results needs to be already displayed in the faceted results view before clicking on "Show Results as Text")